# Java: how to allow choose a variable depending on parameter passed?

Tags: java

This is my class:

```
class StockQuote {

Float[] high, low, close, open;

public float GetMax(String choose_data_type) {
    if data_type="high" {
        Routine_Searchmax(high)
    } elseif strdata_type="low" {
        Routine_Searchmax(low)
    }
}
private float Routine_Searchmax(float[] variable) {
   // here i search max value into my array
}
}
```

My Question is: it is possible to pass a string variable with *the name of a variable array*, then .. work on that specific variable ?
Is there a way to do that ? 
Thanks

Comment: Well you normally don't want to closely couple input data to your internal objects without validation. But you could turn to reflection to retrieve a field dynamically. Have a look at BeanUtils from apache for an idea http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtils.html#getSimpleProperty(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String)

Comment: Your question is unclear. While your syntax is not correct, what you are sketching out here is easily done in Java, just as you outline. Can you explain your statement, "as you know .. I can't do it," because it seems to me that you can do it.

Comment: I fail to see how having four different routines is any different than four sections of a single routine, except that it is easier to verify it's correctness at compile time...

Comment: I think I'd have to see your working code first to see what you're trying to do and then suggest how to improve it.

Comment: I am probably not understanding the question correctly but you are definitely missing a return statement from your method. What is Searchmax()? class? method? if it is a class then you need to use "new" to instantiate the class. If it is a method, what does it return?

Comment: Why not have a map with the data type as the key, and a collection as the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement one single private method that take the name of the variable as parameter and return the corresponding float array. Then you can use this helper method in all the methods that implement you calculation.

If your parameter to identify the variable is an string, then the easyest way to "transform" it to the float array is an kind if-cascade.

```
if(name.equals("high") return this.high;
if(name.equals("low")...
throw new IllegalArgumentExeption();
```

If you have many of this Variables (high, low, ...) then you may should use reflection instead of this if-cascade.

**An impovent would be to use an ENUM instead of the string!**

---

But im my oppinion a much better solution would be using object orientation! Make high, low, ... instances of an class that implements getMax only for its own valus. So you can do this:

```
 MyClass high = new MyClass;
 ...
 float higgMax = high.getMax();
```

Answer (score 1):

A better way is to do it by using enum

**Enum Declaration**

```
public enum Float
{
    HIGHT("high"), LOW("low"), CLOSE("close"), OPEN("open");

    String code;

    Float(String code)
    {
        this.code=code;
    }

   // add getter and setter for string code here 
}
```

**Class Dec**

```
public class StockQuote {

    public Float getMax(String chooseDataType) {

        return routineSearchmax (Float.valueOf(chooseDataType));
    }

    //This float is now enum
    private Float routineSearchmax(Float variable) {
           // here i search max value into my array
        }
}
```

But like these guys are saying you could just do it with out it as well but neater this way in my opinion also notice no if statement.

Comment: By the way forgot mention that you variable and function name were not following JAVA standard conventions of using camel case.